# jQuery converts regular spaces to non-breaking spaces when appending text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a jQuery AJAX callback function that adds the retrieved JSON data as help text to a popup div. Here is the relevant code:

```
ajaxCallback = function(data, status, request) {
    if('string' == typeof data) {
        data = convertStringToJSON(data);
    }

    for(var id in data.fields) {
        var field = data.fields[id];
        $('#' + id + 'Help').text(field.description);
    }
};

function convertStringToJSON(string) {
    if('undefined' == typeof JSON) {
        return eval('(' + string + ');');
    } else {
        return JSON.parse(string);
    }
}
```

I used Firebug to break at the callback so I could check the data, and found no problems with it. Nevertheless, when jQuery appends "field.description" to the selected element, it converts all the spaces in the text to non-breaking spaces (&nbsp;). This breaks the layout of the popup: the text overflows the fixed width. I even used Firebug to manually convert the non-breaking spaces to regular spaces and that fixed the text, so I know it's not a problem with my CSS. (Just to be sure, I checked the white-space property of the div and it is "normal".)

I tried using different approaches to appending the text: .append() and .html() instead of .text(), but those had the same result.

I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 via Google: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

I should explain that I'm retrieving my JSON from a PHP script that uses json_encode(), and the text has some Spanish characters with accents. I see that json_encode() converts the accent characters to Unicode characters (\u chars), but there's no issue with those displaying in the final result.

(Note: I now realize that jQuery has a built-in function to convert plain text to JSON, so the convertStringToJSON function is obsolete. I didn't realize this at the time, perhaps that's the source of my problem?)

EDIT: My bad, this is an issue with PHP. I rephrased the question here: [PHP utf8_encode() converts spaces to non-breaking spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085204/php-utf8-encode-converts-spaces-to-non-breaking-spaces)

Comment: have you examined the string data in data.fields to verify it is not holding nonbreaking spaces?

Comment: Yes, using Firebug at the breakpoint, I looked at the data and found the spacing to be correct.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, I retract my last comment. I was looking at Firebug's JSON tab in the XHR response. I didn't think to look at the raw text response, and now I'm seeing \u00a0 characters everywhere. That must be it.

Comment: I use utf8_encode() in my PHP script to ensure that the Spanish characters are displayed properly. That function must be converting my spaces to non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Doh!  UTF8 strikes again.  Everyone should just speak American. :)

Comment: I tried filtering the utf8_encode() result with str_replace(): str_replace("\u00a0", " ", utf8_encode($dat)). But that didn't fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately we're out of the realm of my expertise.  Your OP does not seem to apply.  You might want to ask a different question.