# PHP utf8_encode() converts spaces to non-breaking spaces

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

Perfectly simple: utf8_encode($string) replaces regular spaces with non-breaking spaces ("\u00a0"). I tried filtering the result with str_replace:

```
str_replace("\u00a0", " ", utf8_encode($string))
```

But that didn't fix it.

EDIT: Sigh, I'm an idiot. It's not a problem with utf8_encode() either. I thought I was using that function, forgot I disabled it in my code. My data is being run through json_encode() for an AJAX request. Is it a problem with json_encode()? I worry I may be guilty of abusing Stack Overflow. I'll try Googling it.

FINAL EDIT: Problem was with the data itself, which was copied from a Word document into a MySQL table. All the spaces were copied as non-breaking spaces. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: The question being, how can I get my regular spaces back?

Comment: If the string is UTF-8 encoded, you have to replace the corresponding sequence of code units rather than the codepoint value itself.

Comment: What's your input? 0xA0 is the non-breaking space in ISO 8859-1 also.

Answer (score 12):

> str_replace("\u00a0", " ", utf8_encode($dat)). But that didn't fix it.

PHP only has byte strings, not native Unicode strings; consequently there is no `\u` escape and you were asking it literally to convert backslash-letter-u sequences in the input.

To get rid of non-breaking space characters you would have to replace away `\xA0` (if done over the ISO-8859-1 data you presumably have before passing to `utf8_encode`), or `\xC2\xA0` (if done after transcoding to UTF-8).

`utf8_encode` only transcodes ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, it doesn't touch spaces, so my suspicion is you have non-breaking space characters in your actual data.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$str = trim($str, chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0))
```

Answer (score -1):

#### json_decode error, cause non breaking space (\xc2\xa0)

before json_decoding, do this ...

```
     $data = str_replace("\xc2\xa0",'',$data)
     $json = json_decode($data);
```